# What are the equivalents of AWSXRay captureHTTPsGlobal and captureAWS methods in @aws-sdk/client-xray?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-xray

In my code, I'm using [`aws-xray-sdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-xray-sdk) at the moment and I want to migrate to `@aws-sdk/client-xray`, [XRay Client - AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-xray/index.html). I have the following piece of code and my question is what would be a replacement for it using the new xray client? Apart from XRay, I use S3, SES, and SQS.

```
  import * as https from 'https';
  import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk';
  import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

  AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(https, false);
  AWSXRay.captureAWS(AWS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AWS SDK for JavaScript v3` and `AWS XRay SDK for node` they are 2 different packages. Migrating AWS SDK for JavaScript from v2 to v3 means user has to modify their application code by following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html

If user is using `AWS XRay SDK for node` instrument `AWS SDK for JavaScript v3` in his application, please follow instruction https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#capture-outgoing-aws-requests-on-a-single-client

Comment: Thank you. Those are the instructions I needed.